# Alternative to UNION ALL in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, union

I am trying to recreate this query without using UNION ALL statement, I have tried 
Scalar Subqueries and the model clause but none seem to do what I want. My manager doesn't want to use Union All but I don't really see what the alternative is

any help would be great

```
SELECT null AS UDA_ID,
       'Style-Level Attributes' AS UDA_DESC,
       null AS DISPLAY_TYPE,
       null AS REQUIRED_IND,
       null AS ITEM,
       null AS UDA_TEXT,
       null AS UDA_DATE,
       null AS UDA_VALUE
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL                 
select a.UDA_ID,
       a.UDA_DESC,
       a.DISPLAY_TYPE,
       a.REQUIRED_IND,
       b.ITEM,
       b.UDA_TEXT,
       b.UDA_DATE,
       b.UDA_VALUE              
from   DAL.P_UDA a,
       FFEDEV.FFE_ITEM_UDA b                
where  a.UDA_ID = b.UDA_ID (+)                
AND    a.REQUIRED_IND IS NOT NULL       
AND    b.ITEM_PARENT IS NULL      
UNION ALL
SELECT null AS UDA_ID,
       'Additional Attributes' AS UDA_DESC,
       null AS DISPLAY_TYPE,
       null AS REQUIRED_IND,
       null AS ITEM,
       null AS UDA_TEXT,
       null AS UDA_DATE,
       null AS UDA_VALUE
FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL                
select a.UDA_ID,
       a.UDA_DESC,
       a.DISPLAY_TYPE,
       a.REQUIRED_IND,
       b.ITEM,
       b.UDA_TEXT,
       b.UDA_DATE,
       b.UDA_VALUE         
from   DAL.P_UDA a,
       FFEDEV.FFE_ITEM_UDA b                
where  a.UDA_ID = b.UDA_ID (+)                
AND    a.REQUIRED_IND IS NULL      
AND    b.ITEM_PARENT IS NULL
```

Comment: This is why `UNION` was created. If you insist on doing it, you can use `FULL OUTER JOIN ON(1 = 2)` between all this queries, and `NVL` or `CASE EXPRESSION` to replace the null values, that will do the same as union.

Comment: It is strange to use a result row as a header. Selected rows should only contain data. So you should add a column containing 'Style-Level Attributes' or 'Additional Attributes' to your result rows instead. Then your query is not guaranteed to work as you want it to work. Without an `ORDER BY` clause there is no guaranteed sorting. All that `UNION ALL` promises is that the rows get in the results, not in what order. Once your query gets executed in parallel threads you may see your records all mixed. Then you shouldn't use a join syntax any longer that has Long been deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that in your query the only real functional difference is in the two `WHERE` clauses.  In the first half of the `UNION ALL` the condition has:

```
WHERE a.REQUIRED_IND IS NOT NULL
```

while the second half has:

```
WHERE a.REQUIRED_IND IS NULL
```

You can use a `CASE` expression to generate a computed column containing the attribute type.  For clarity, here is that `CASE` expression by itself:

```
CASE WHEN a.REQUIRED_IND IS NOT NULL
    THEN 'Style-Level Attributes'
    ELSE 'Additional Attributes'
END AS UDA_DESC
```

And here is the full query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.REQUIRED_IND IS NOT NULL THEN 'Style-Level Attributes' ELSE 'Additional Attributes' END AS AttrType,
    a.UDA_ID, a.UDA_DESC, a.DISPLAY_TYPE, a.REQUIRED_IND, b.ITEM, b.UDA_TEXT, b.UDA_DATE, b.UDA_VALUE
FROM DAL.P_UDA a
LEFT OUTER JOIN FFEDEV.FFE_ITEM_UDA b
    ON a.UDA_ID = b.UDA_ID
WHERE b.ITEM_PARENT IS NULL
ORDER BY AttrType
```

The only major potential setback in this query is that you lose the two null header rows.  However, for reporting purposes there should be no problem.  If your boss insists on those null header rows, then tell him that they are synthesized data and the only way to add them to the result set is by doing a `UNION`.

Comment: I think you need to remove the `REQUIRED_IND IS NOT NULL` , that's what you explained . Also, the default null row will be lost. You should also answer here with the correct join syntax

Comment: This causes an invalid identifier because the first statement is a selection from dual, not the required tables.

Comment: Since we can now include the attribute type for each record, there is no need for the `null` header rows, which I have removed.  Instead, I added a new column with this type.

Comment: Good explanation, and I agree that one shouldn't introduce title rows, but have the information in a column instead. sagi is right though concerning `AND a.REQUIRED_IND IS NOT NULL` spoiling your intentions and that the out-dated join syntax should be discouraged.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the adf application requires the fields to be in the table to populate.

Comment: Hey Tim, that was an outer join before your last edit :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Are you certain the `AND a.REQUIRED_IND` is even needed?  I removed it.

Comment: I am certain it had to be removed in order to make your query work as intended :-)

Comment: @James: As Tim mentioned; if you want to add created title rows you need `UNION ALL` (or very dirty tricks). Add a sort key in that case so as to get your data ordered properly.

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured as much but I thought there might be some trick I was missing out on. Thanks again for you help and good solution.